# Parse.com - Parse.Object.extend(...) attributes

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

I'm working with Parse JS and Backbone, and I trying print a list of values from model of Parse JS. It's easy, but I have problem with objectId.

Then, I have...

```
var Thing = Parse.Object.extend('MyThings');
var Things = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: Thing
});

var collection = new Things();
collection.fetch({
    success: function(){
        App.start(collection.toJSON());
    }
});
```

This is the view...

```
ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(_.template($('#item-template').html(), this.model.attributes));
    }
});

ThingListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    addAll: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.addAll();
    },
    addOne: function(item){
        var itemView = new ThingView({model: item});
        itemView.render();
        this.$el.append(itemView.el);
    }
});
```

And this is a template (with Underscore.js)...

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <td><%= id %></td>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= color %></td>
</script>
```

The attributes name and color are shown correctly, but '*id is not defined*'

Any idea?

Comment: where is the view for <tr>? have you set idAttributes?

Comment: #item-template is encapsulated in <tr></tr> (tagName: 'tr') . Name and color are attributes, but id is the objectId assigned by Parse. Both attributes are shown correctly, but in console shown 'ReferenceError: id is not defined'

Comment: I don't see any references to `id` attribute in the [`Parse.Object` documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html). Are you sure you're not talking about the `cid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **id** doesn't live in attributes. It actually lives at the root of the object. So what you'll need to do is pass *this.model* into _.template() instead of *this.model.attributes*, and then adjust accordingly in your HTML - such as the following:

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(_.template($('#item-template').html(), this.model));
}

<td><%= id %></td>
<td><%= attributes.name %></td>
<td><%= attributes.color %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already solved in another way, but your solution is better.

Comment: I'm curious, what was the other solution that you put in place?

Comment: Add an attribute id: this.model.attributes.id = this.model.id;